# HTTPError: Forbidden

Tags: python, http-error

I get `HTTPError: Forbidden` error when trying to read from a website that requires feedback response in the form of radio buttons. How to resolve this ???

An example url link that causes the error is commented out:
`url = 'http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/news/market-news/market-news-detail/WWH/13673174.html'`

Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request as req
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# get all text from websites.
url = 'https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football'
#url = 'http://www.londonstockexchange.com/exchange/news/market-news/market-news-detail/WWH/13673174.html'
html = req.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# kill all script and style elements
for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out

# get text
text = soup.get_text()

# break into lines and remove leading and trailing space on each
lines = (line.strip() for line in text.splitlines())
# break multi-headlines into a line each
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
# drop blank lines
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)

print(text)
```

Comment: You can try using `selenium` to simulate the radio button selection and button click.